# Check if a string contains matching brackets

Tags: c#, strings, balanced-delimiters

Trying to solve a case for a set of multiple types of brackets.

```
class BracketHelper {
    // checks if the string contains properly formatted brackets
    public static bool ProperBrackets(string s) {
        int p = 0;
        return ProperBrackets(s.ToCharArray(), ref p);
    }

    // main method, uses recursion to check if the brackets are properly formatted
    private static bool ProperBrackets(char[] arr, ref int ptr, char oppBracket = ' ') {

        for(;ptr<arr.Length;ptr++) {
            var ch = arr[ptr];

            if ( IsOpen(ch)) {  // found an open bracket - let's check the inner content
                ptr +=1; // start checking from the next position
                if (ProperBrackets(arr, ref ptr, OppositeOf(ch)) == false) // inner content is malformed?
                    return false;
            }
            if ( IsClose(ch) ) // found a closing bracket
                return ch == oppBracket; // is this what we were looking for? If not - then we found a malformity!
        }

        // we reached the end. are we still searching for the closing bracket?
        return oppBracket == ' ';
    }

    private static char[] OpenBrackets = new char[] { '{', '[', '(' };
    private static char[] CloseBrackets = new char[] { '}', ']', ')' };

    // check helpers
    private static bool IsOpen(char ch)  {      return OpenBrackets.Contains(ch);       }
    private static bool IsClose(char ch) {      return CloseBrackets.Contains(ch);      }

    // returns a closing bracket character
    private static char OppositeOf(char ch) {
        for(var i=0;i<OpenBrackets.Length;i+=1)
            if ( ch == OpenBrackets[i] ) 
                return CloseBrackets[i];
        throw new Exception($"'{ch}' is not an open bracket");
    }
}
```

Some test cases for LinqPad:

```
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{}") == true).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[]()}") == true).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[()][{}]{}}") == true).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[}]}") == false).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[{(}])}") == false).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[][][][{(})}]}") == false).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[]}}") == false).Dump();
(BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{") == false).Dump();
```

This can be done with the `ref` argument, so the pointer is a member of a class but in this case the method won't be static and I just wanted to make its usage as convenient as possible.

Comment: Are you checking for just balance or proper nesting and balance?

Comment: @tinstaafl looking at the fifth test case it looks like nesting and balance

Comment: That's the usual case, but the OP isn't being explicit about it.

Answer (score 5):

Let's first take a look at the code

- The code could use some space to breathe by adding spaces before and after operators. For example `for(;ptr<arr.Length;ptr++)` would be more readable like
  `for (; ptr < arr.Length; ptr++)`
- The expected bracing style would be to place an opening bracket on a new line.
- Omitting braces `{}` although they might be optional can lead to hidden and therefor hard to find bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use them.
- Comments should describe **why** something is done. Comments like `if ( IsClose(ch) ) // found a closing bracket` are superflous and reduce the readability of the code.
- I know that naming things is a hard task but one should at least try to do this in a way that a reader of the code can grasp the meaning of a variable fast which isn'tthe case for `oppBracket`.  If a method returns a `bool` one should name that method like a question. E.g `AreBracketsProper` would be a better name.

---

Using recursion is a way one can use, but recursion isn't the holy grail for such a task. You need a `ref int` and an optional `oppBracket` to achieve the goal by using recursion.

I would use a `Stack<Stack<T>>` for keeping track of the nesting levels and instead of two `char[]` arrays I would use two strings and would use `IndexOf(char)` to get the index of a bracket and to check if the current char is a bracket at all.

If I find an opening bracket I will create a new `Stack<int>` which contains the value of `openingBrackets.IndexOf()` and then I will `Push()` it on the `Stack<Stack<int>>`. If I find an closing bracket I will take the last index from the `Stack<int>` if ther is any and check if it is the same as the value returned from `closingBrackets.IndexOf()`. This coul truned into an extension method as well, like so

```
static class BracketHelper
{
    private const string openingBrackets = "{[(";
    private const string closingBrackets = "}])";

    public static bool AreBracketsProper(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)); }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) { return true; }

        var stacks = new Stack<Stack<int>>();
        var currentStack = new Stack<int>();
        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            var bracketIndex = 0;
            if ((bracketIndex = openingBrackets.IndexOf(c)) > -1)
            {
                currentStack = new Stack<int>();
                currentStack.Push(bracketIndex);
                stacks.Push(currentStack);
            }
            else if ((bracketIndex = closingBrackets.IndexOf(c)) > -1)
            {
                while (currentStack.Count == 0 && stacks.Count > 0)
                {
                    currentStack = stacks.Pop();
                }

                if (currentStack.Count == 0 || bracketIndex != currentStack.Pop()) { return false; }
            }
        }
        return stacks.Count == 0 || stacks.Pop().Count == 0;
    }
}
```

Which could be called as an extension method like so

```
("{}".AreBracketsProper() == true).Dump();
("{[]()}".AreBracketsProper() == true).Dump();
("{[()][{}]{}}".AreBracketsProper() == true).Dump();
("{[}]}".AreBracketsProper() == false).Dump();
("{[{(}])}".AreBracketsProper() == false).Dump();
("{[][][][{(})}]}".AreBracketsProper() == false).Dump();
("{[]}}".AreBracketsProper() == false).Dump();
("{".AreBracketsProper() == false).Dump();
("}".AreBracketsProper() == false).Dump();
```

Comment: I really like this answer and the explanation.  Suggestion: you could move the declaration for `bracketIndex` and `currentStack` to be inside the `foreach` since that seems to be the limit of their scope.

Comment: Agreed on `bracketIndex` and edited. `currentStack` needs to be declared outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with the points made by Heslacher:

- You should not omit brackets
- Better naming leads you to need less comments
- Comments should explain **why** if the code is not explicit

also:

- You should add some parameter validation since it's going to be a public method, every public method should validate its parameters before doing any job.

I also think this is such a simple task, no need to use recursion. I would use a [`Dictionary<char, char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to map each opening bracket with its closing bracket, have a [`HashSet<char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) for closing brackets check purpose and a [`Stack<char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) to push each opening bracket and pop its closing bracket. In case there is a closing bracket mismatch returns `false`, in the end if there are still open brackets in the stack, it means there are brackets mismatch:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<char, char> brackets = new Dictionary<char, char>() {
    { '(', ')' },
    { '[', ']' },
    { '{', '}' }
};

private static readonly HashSet<char> closingBrackets = new HashSet<char>(brackets.Values);

public static bool AreBracketsProper(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }
    if (value.Length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var openBrackets = new Stack<char>();
    foreach (char chr in value)
    {
        if (brackets.ContainsKey(chr))
        {
            openBrackets.Push(chr);
            continue;
        }
        if (!closingBrackets.Contains(chr))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (openBrackets.Count == 0 || brackets[openBrackets.Peek()] != chr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        openBrackets.Pop();
    }
    return openBrackets.Count == 0;
}
```

I would not make it an extension though, because I think it would pollute string methods with a kind of specific functionality.

I am also assuming that no brackets means they are proper.

Answer (score 2):

The general issues in your code have already been mentioned in other answers so I'll just post a simpler solution.

---

You only need a single stack where you put all the left/opening brackets. When you find a right/closing bracket you pop a left one from the stack. If it doesn't match the current right bracket then you know they are not balanced. It works with all your test cases.

```
public static bool Balanced(this string value)
{
    var openingBrackets = new Stack<char>();

    foreach (var c in value)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '(':
            case '[':
            case '{':
                openingBrackets.Push(c);
                break;
            case ')': if (!TryPop(out var openingRound) || openingRound != '(') return false; break;
            case ']': if (!TryPop(out var openingSquare) || openingSquare != '[') return false; break;
            case '}': if (!TryPop(out var openingCurly) || openingCurly != '{') return false; break;
        }
    }

    return !openingBrackets.Any();

    bool TryPop(out char opening)
    {
        if (openingBrackets.Any())
        {
            opening = openingBrackets.Pop();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            opening = '\0';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

> ```
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{}") == true).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[]()}") == true).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[()][{}]{}}") == true).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[}]}") == false).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[{(}])}") == false).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[][][][{(})}]}") == false).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{[]}}") == false).Dump();
> (BracketHelper.ProperBrackets("{") == false).Dump();
> ```

I don't like your test cases because it's too much copy/paste. Creating an array with test-cases and expected results would simplify it.

```
var data = new (string TestCase, bool Balanced)[]
{
    ("{}", true),
    ("{[]()}", true),
    ("{[()][{}]{}}", true),
    ("{[}]}", false),
    ("{[{(}])}", false),
    ("{[][][][{(})}]}", false),
    ("{[]}}", false),
    ("{", false)
};

data.Select(x => (x.TestCase.Balanced() == x.Balanced)).Dump();
```